# Counter Won't Increment in Nested For Loop - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I am looping through a column and count the number of times each row appears in another column. This works once, displaying the correct counts. However in subsequent it only displys zero for all rows. I stepped through the code and the counter values won't update. I appreciate it if somebody take a look.

```
    Sub count_tic_types()
        Dim ticCountGraph   As Worksheet
        Dim CWData          As Worksheet
        '' Row count for ticCountGraph.
        Dim i               As Integer
        '' Row count for CWData
        Dim j               As Integer
        Dim ticCount        As Integer
        Dim ticAlert        As Integer

        Set ticCountGraph = Worksheets("ticCountGraph")
        Set CWData = Worksheets("CWData")


        For i = 1 To 9

            '' Start the counters fresh for each new row. Ensures that
            '' there's no double counting.
            ticCount = 0
            ticAlert = 0

            '' Loop through entire target column to count the number of
            '' matches there.
            For j = 2 To CWData.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

                '' Want to count values that have been Closed.
                If Range("I" & j).Value = "Closed" Then

                    '' Increment if there are mathces.
                    If CWData.Range("J" & j).Value = ticCountGraph.Range("A" & i).Value Then
                            ticCount = ticCount + 1

                    '' Count blank values separately.
                    ElseIf IsEmpty(CWData.Range("J" & j)) Then
                            ticAlert = ticAlert + 1

                    End If
                End If
            Next

            If ticCountGraph.Range("A" & i).Value = "Alerts" Then
                ticCountGraph.Range("B" & i).Value = ticAlert
            Else
                ticCountGraph.Range("B" & i).Value = ticCount
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

The column where `i` will be looping through.
[image]

The column where `j` will loop through and count the number of occurrences
that match each row in above image.

[image]

Comment: Range("A" & 1) should this 1 also increment or be a var like j?

Comment: I think you should give some more info about the goal of your code and data to test it. some blind shots: 1) add sheet reference to `Range("I" & j)`. 2) `ticCount` counter gets incremented when values in column J equals ticCountGraph.Range("A" & i)` but if this latter is "Alerts" you don't write down `ticCount` counter `...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it now. The issue may be the `Range("I"&j).Value` with the unspecified worksheet. After I specified it with `CWData`, it works.

LESSON: When working with ranges from different worksheets, make sure to prefix all functions with the correct worksheet name.

```
For i = 2 To 10

    '' Start the counters fresh for each new row. Ensures that
    '' there's no double counting.
    ticCount = 0
    ticAlert = 0

    For j = 2 To CWData.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

        '' THIS IS THE PART THAT REQUIRED WORKSHEET NAME.
        If CWData.Range("I" & j).Value <> ">Cancelled" Then
            If CWData.Range("J" & j).Value = ticCountGraph.Range("A" & i).Value Then
                    ticCount = ticCount + 1
            ElseIf IsEmpty(CWData.Range("J" & j)) Then
                    ticAlert = ticAlert + 1

            End If
        End If
    Next j
    If ticCountGraph.Range("A" & i).Value = "Alerts" Then
        ticCountGraph.Range("B" & i).Value = ticAlert
    Else
        ticCountGraph.Range("B" & i).Value = ticCount
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Good job, glad you found it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub count_tic_types()
    Dim ticCountGraph   As Worksheet
    Dim CWData          As Worksheet
    '' Row count for ticCountGraph.
    Dim i               As Integer
    '' Row count for CWData
    Dim j               As Integer
    Dim ticCount        As Integer
    Dim ticAlert        As Integer

    Set ticCountGraph = Worksheets("ticCountGraph")
    Set CWData = Worksheets("CWData")

    For i = 1 To 9

        '' Start the counters fresh for each new row. Ensures that
        '' there's no double counting.
        ticCount = 0
        ticAlert = 0

        For j = 2 To CWData.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

            If Range("I" & j).Value = "Closed" Then

                If CWData.Range("J" & j).Value = ticCountGraph.Range("A" & i).Value Then
                        ticCount = ticCount + 1

                ElseIf IsEmpty(CWData.Range("J" & j)) Then
                        ticAlert = ticAlert + 1

                End If
            End If
        Next j  ' forgot j

        If ticCountGraph.Range("A" & i).Value = "Alerts" Then
            ticCountGraph.Range("B" & i).Value = ticAlert
        Else
            ticCountGraph.Range("B" & i).Value = ticCount
        End If
    Next i ' forgot i
End Sub
```

Comment: @Dombey Is ticCount and ticAlert supposed to be reset to 0 on each loop?

Comment: @Dombey I can't see how the code checks different rows. I can see how the "j" loop does, but the "i" loop just does the same thing over and over again. Or?? It's hard to understand with no data to test it on.